# Initialize base class with data from derived class with django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there any way to inherit a django model and initialize a base class field with data in the derived class, like this :

```
class InitialModel(models.Model):
    evolution_list = ('1', '2', '3')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=evolution_list)
    # choices will be : '1', '2', '3'

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class NextModel(InitialModel):
    evolution_list = ('4', '5', '6')
    # version : choices will be : '1', '2', '3'
    # wanted version choices are : '4', '5', '6'
```

Actually, I know that it is possible to do it by charging the field:

```
class NextModel(InitialModel):
    evolution_list = ('4', '5', '6')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=evolution_list)
```

Is there a better, and cleanner way?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why wont you make two different models with different version options?

Comment: @Najiva I wanted to do that because I have some logic in the InitialModel, I need to keep